# Живая трансляция экрана с помощью ffmpeg и ffserver (ОС Linux)

Tags: ffmpeg

Добрый день.

Мне хотелось бы организовать трансляцию экрана своего компютера в интернет так что бы можно было открыть ссылку на трансляцию в браузере и смотреть, подскажите можно ли это в принципе сделать с помощью ffmpeg и ffserver + какого нибуть web сервера который отдаст html страничку с блоком video и каким нибуть проигрывателем mp4? Почитал документацию, посмотрел интернеты, вроде бы это возможно но наверняка есть куча мелочей вроде правильного кодека, его параметров и т.п. Попробовал запустить с такими параметрами:

ffserver.conf (нашёл где то в интернете):

```
HTTPPort 8090
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 10000
CustomLog -

<Feed av_feed.ffm>
    File /tmp/av_feed.ffm
    FileMaxSize 1G
    ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Feed>

<Feed streamwebm.ffm>
    File /tmp/streamwebm.ffm
    FileMaxSize 50M
    ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Feed>

<Stream streamwebm>
    Feed streamwebm.ffm
    Format webm

    # Video Settings
    VideoFrameRate 10
    VideoSize 1920x1080

    # Audio settings
    AudioCodec libvorbis
    AudioSampleRate 48000
    AVOptionAudio flags +global_header

    MaxTime 0
    AVOptionVideo me_range 16
    AVOptionVideo qdiff 4
    AVOptionVideo qmin 4
    AVOptionVideo qmax 40
    #AVOptionVideo good
    AVOptionVideo flags +global_header

    # Streaming settings
    PreRoll 10
    StartSendOnKey

    Metadata author "author"
    Metadata copyright "copyright"
    Metadata title "Web app name"
    Metadata comment "comment"
</Stream>

<Stream stat.html>
    Format status
    ACL allow localhost
    ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
</Stream>
<Redirect index.html>
    URL http://www.ffmpeg.org/
</Redirect>
```

так запускаю ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1920x1080 -r 10 -i $DISPLAY -f alsa -i default -c:v libvpx -cpu-used 4 -threads 4 http://localhost:8090/streamwebm.ffm
```

Рядом с ffserver запустил http сервер на 8000 порту который отдаёт такую страничку:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <video src="http://localhost:8090/streamwebm" controls></video>
</body>
</html>
```

Когда нажимаю кнопку play ничего не происходит.

Знающие люди подскажите что не так? Может проще это сделать с помощью других программ?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Ни разу получить нормально рабочей системы с ffserver не выходило. Возьми nginx-rtmp и настрой стриминг при помощи него: он сможет сам запустить ffmpeg с нужными опциями. Ну или запустить публикацию самостоятельно после. Как удобнее будет.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую nginx. Если получится сообщу.

Comment: да, насколько я знаю, веб проигрывателей на HTML5 для rtmp нет. Но я могу чего-то не знать.

Comment: Поддерживаю! ffserver какой-то совсем косой. Даже в icecast2 все нормально сливается и работает, не то что тут.

Кстати, тотуриал, где nginx стартует ffmpeg при каждом подключении, мягко говоря, кривой: так делать не нужно. На всю трансляцию нужен один транскодер, а не каждому клиенту - свой.

Comment: @MonahTuk flowplayer в этом смысле довольно не плох - он если flash-движок загрузить не может, спрыгивает на HLS или WebM

Comment: @gbg для HLS на nginx-rtmp нужно чуууууточку больше телодвижений. А ещё латенси до 10 сек у HLS это норма. Напарывались. Знаем. При интерактивной демонстрации рабочего стола - не самый торт. А вот WebM nginx-rtmp, насколько я знаю, не может. Ну а ставить Wowza - это уже моветон :) Что ещё сможет http+webm или http+mp4 - я не знаю, а какая при этом задержка будет - тем более. Кстати, DASH тоже задержку давать будет, как и HLS.

Comment: @MonahTuk согласен, HLC - он медлителен. WebM можно отдавать через icecast2 - работает. Задержка-удовлетворительная.

Comment: @gbg спасибо за наводку. ТСу тоже полезно будет.

Answer (score 0):

Вот 100% рабочая конфигурация связки FFserver+FFmpeg для задачи трансляции видео на сайт [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/78677/)

Для скринкаста измените вызов

```
ffmpeg -s 352x288 -r 30 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 http://localhost:8090/feed.ffm
```

например на такой

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -g 500 -s 352x288 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -vcodec copy http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

Comment: Ответы-ссылки не приветствуются из-за того, что ссылка может оказаться недействительной в будущем. Для улучшения добавьте необходимый код в свой ответ, ссылка должна быть как источник.

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: теперь вылетает сообщение:
Missing audio stream which is required by this ffm

Comment: Добавьте опцию отключения аудио -an:
fmpeg -r 30 -g 500 -s 352x288 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -an -vcodec copy http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm